# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at 3-way quicksort (C++)

Tags: c++, exception, quicksort

I tried to implement the 3-way quicksort algorithm in C++, described [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/Quick3way.java.html).
Unfortunality I get the exception STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

```
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
void qsort(std::array<T, SIZE> &a, std::size_t lo, std::size_t hi) {

    if (hi <= lo) {
        return;
    }

    std::size_t lt = lo, gt = hi;
    T v = a[lo];
    std::size_t i = lo;

    while (i <= gt) {
        if (a[i] < v) {
            std::swap(a[lt++], a[i++]);
        } else if (a[i] > v) {
            std::swap(a[i], a[gt--]);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    qsort(a, lo, lt - 1);
    qsort(a, gt + 1, hi);
}

template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
void quickSortThreeWay(std::array<T, SIZE> &a) {
    std::size_t arraySize = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    qsort(a, 0, arraySize - 1);
}
```

The array is a std::array I filled with random values. This works fine with other algorithms.

Can you help me find the problem? Thanks.

Thank you.

Comment: Provide a minimal example including the values that cause the error. See also the stack overflow guidelines.

Comment: Did you try using the debugger? And, also, describe to me, what will happen in the line `qsort(a, lo, lt - 1);` if `lt` is equal to `0`?

Comment: *The array is a std::array I filled with random values*  -- You should start with non-random, known values, and only maybe 10 or less of these values.  Then debug your code, step by step, to see where the program does something unexpected that goes against the algorithm.

Comment: sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])  isn't how you get number of elements in a container, use a.size()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line of code:

```
qsort(a, lo, lt - 1);
```

When lo is 0, lt can be -1.  Unfortunately, your signature doesn't allow negative numbers because you are using size_t, so in my test, when lo is 0, lt - 1 is 18446744073709551615.  This test then fails to do what you want:

```
if (hi <= lo) { return }
```

Then it blindly goes on and crashes.  You might think to allow negative numbers in your method signature instead of size_t, eg:

```
void qsort(std::array<T, SIZE> &a, int lo, int hi) {
    std::cout << "qsort (a, " << lo << ", " << hi << ")" << std::endl;
```

When I run the above modified signature against an array of three strings:

```
std::array<std::string, 3> a;
a[0] = "hello";
a[1] = "abacus";
a[2] = "goodbye";
quickSortThreeWay (a);
```

I get -1 for that last parameter:

```
qsort (a, 0, 2)
qsort (a, 0, 1)
qsort (a, 0, -1)
qsort (a, 1, 1)
qsort (a, 3, 2)
```